# Using chrome.runtime.sendMessage in an imported javascript file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm currently using jQuery's $.getScript within my content script to import more Javascript files into my content script. This works very well for me to get all my Javascript files imported, but I am running into an issue where I can't use chrome.runtime.sendMessage inside the imported javascript files to communicate with my background scripts, presumably because the function isn't recognized within a script that's been processed by $.getScript (please do correct me if I'm wrong).

In **content.js** (injected directly via the manifest file), I have the following code:

```
$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('js/angular-1.2.26-min.js'), function(data) {
  $.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('app/app.js'), function(data) {
    $.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('app/overview/overview-controller.js'), function(data) {
      $.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL('js/angular-bootstrap.js'), function(data) {
      })
    })
  })
})
```

And inside **app/app.js** (or any of the injected files), I try putting a sendMessage call anywhere, but nothing gets sent. (I log the onMessage event listener in the background)

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: 'test'}, function(response) { alert('done') })
```

Note: I have also tried importing the Javascript files by sending a message to the background script to use chrome.tabs.executeScrip instead, but I need to be able to inject the javascript files only at a specific time and in a specific frame, so that doesn't help. I've also tried using the 3rd party [executeScriptInFrame library](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/chrome.tabs.executeScriptInFrame) but that doesn't seem to be working either. I run into *"Blocked script execution in '{{URL}}' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set"*

My questions:

- Is there an effective solution to using chrome.runtime.sendMessage inside a script that's been injected using $.getScript?
- Is there a way to use executeScript inside a content script?
- Is there an effective way to inject content scripts into a particular frame? Again, from above -- I tried a third party library but ran into an issue regarding the frame's sandboxing. But this is strange since I am able to successfully inject content scripts to that frame when using the manifest to do it directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's an interesting question.

Most methods rely `<script>` injection, which adds code to the wrong (page) context that has no access to Chrome APIs. I assume this is how `$.getScript` works. So, this will not work as intended.

Another method is using `eval()`. According to [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions), `eval()` is allowed (but discouraged) in Content Scripts. So you can, in principle, load the script file in a XHR / jQuery AJAX request and then `eval()` its contents. **This should work.**

Lastly, you could modify your content scripts only to execute if some condition is met (say, a variable is set), and so injecting into all frames of a tab should be less of a problem. This could potentially be messy though. Note that a content script can [find itself in the iframe hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010355/is-there-a-way-to-uniquely-identify-an-iframe-that-the-content-script-runs-in-fo/26014716#26014716), which may be useful.