# How to tell in content script that I am loading the top window and not an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I need a way to know in my Chrome extension when running the content script that the frame being loaded is not an iframe. I am trying to construct an array of objects containing the URL's that the user has traveled to (see below). I need to set all_frames to true in my manifest file because I also have to be able to access elements inside iframes. Does anyone know how I can know if the frame currently running my content script is the window and not an iframe?

```
//if(window is not iframe)
    sendData({Task : "Load Page", Path : location.href});
```

Comment: See also: [Is there a way to uniquely identify an iframe that the content script runs in for my Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26010355/934239)

Comment: Okay thank you, was unable to find that originally, but it did help. :)