# Access iframe content from different domain through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a chrome extension that reads a value from an input element inside of an iframe, which src indicates to a completely different domain.

I already tried including

```
"all_frames": true,
```

into the manifest.json, but it seems to get called through a script.

I can see it inside of the "inspect elements" tool, so I assumed that would work, but now I am kind of stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a script that is injected with `all_frames: true` AND matches both domains, then you have 2 *separate* instances of content scripts.

They can either talk [using `postMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication), or through the background page using [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) (unfortunately, Messaging API can't work directly between them).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26010355/934239) may be useful as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually forgot to put the iframe domain into the matches

Comment: For logical separation you may want to have two separate content scripts in the manifest.